# Which configuration property will fix the default imports?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am build my project using vite babel typescript and dynamic import

Dev build is working fine

But production build had some strange problem

I see that some function named `_interopRequireWildcard` calls the function `_typeofB`

`_typeofB` - not callable, but they have a `default` method

```js
_typeofB = {
  default: ƒ _typeofA(obj)
  __esModule: true
}
```

What configuration property can affect this?

i.e. bundle code with error:

```js
import {a7 as getAugmentedNamespace, a8 as _typeofA, ...} from './vendor.js';

var requireA = /*@__PURE__*/getAugmentedNamespace(_typeofA);

var _typeofB = requireA;

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj, nodeInterop) {
    if (obj === null || _typeofB(obj) !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function") {
                        ^^^^^^^^ - _typeofB is not a function
        return {
            "default": obj
        };
    }
   ...
}
```

That works if I manually add:

```js
    if (obj === null || _typeofB["default"](obj) !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function") {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can you show us the code (i.e. the module with the export and the code with the `import()` statement)?

Comment: I do not know where exactly in my code the error occurs
It looks like a problem in the way the browser import vendor chunk

Comment: I found this
I'm using `react-awesome-query-builder` and when importing some stuff errors occurred in `react-awesome-query-builder/lib/utils/stuff`:

`var _typeB = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof");`

I think these deps are not being transpile correctly